# What tools or techniques do people use to make Javascript APIs more transparent?

Tags: javascript, ide

In all the ways I've worked with Javascript, I find that nothing ever satisfies my desire for self-documenting code. I want to be able to see the APIs of modules, functions, "struct" fields, and event payloads within my own code.

I'm curious if any IDEs or transpiled languages help people easily keep their internal API visible? For example, with many languages, often an IDE will give an expandable tree view of packages/modules/classes/functions. Javascript makes this difficult as there are so many ways to code all of these entities.

I find when writing an application in Javascript that after it reaches a certain size, I have to keep jumping between source files to remember these things. Consistent naming, clear coding style, and such good habits only go so far. In a language that has no static typing, very loose rules around function arguments, and passing functions as callbacks, JS code can be hard to scan and immediately see the higher-level structure. It's hard to separate interface from implementation, as all JS code is implementation.

In large projects with many programmers, it makes sense to enforce rules about documenting functions in comments and maybe auto-generate docs. But doing independent development, this is like a lot of manual work just to remind oneself of the architecture and internal API, and likely to be out of date most of the time. I'm not going to look up a function to remember what params it takes, see that it has no docstring comments, add them and rebuild the docs so I can go read them.

TypeScript sounds promising but seems too tied to Microsoft tools. CoffeeScript saves typing and can make for cleaner code, but I don't think it solves the problem of exposing a high-level view of the structure of an application.

WebStorm actually exposes some of what I'm looking for, but I wonder what else exists.

I'm looking for any tips, tools, techniques others use to mitigate this issue.

Comment: This may be better suited for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: They told me it would be better suited here :/

Comment: That's why I said "may" ;) However, this question seems to be too broad / discussion oriented for SO.